# Have I made a mistake? Christoffel symbols in isothermal coordinates for the 2-sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification

I see exactly what mistake I originally made. In a few places I mistakenly used the inverse metric where I was meant to use the metric. I reworked it by hand to make sure I get the correct answer

$$\Gamma^\theta=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -\tanh\psi \\\ -\tanh\psi & 0\end{pmatrix} \\ \Gamma^\psi=\begin{pmatrix}\tanh\psi & 0 \\\ 0 & -\tanh\psi\end{pmatrix}$$

and everything came out fine as expected. It was a rather silly mistake. Taking the proper care to not misplace terms would have prevented it.

---

Is there a website out there where I can check my work on Christoffel symbol calculations?

And in general, is there an alternate route to checking one's work on these calculations that isn't just repeating the exact same calculations carefully?

The 2-sphere of radius $R$ in isothermal coordinates is given by:
$$f(\theta,\psi)=(R\cos(\theta)\operatorname{sech}(\psi),R\sin(\theta)\operatorname{sech}(\psi),R\tanh(\psi))$$
where $\theta$ $\in$ $[0,2\pi)$ and $\psi$ $\in$ $(-\infty,\infty)$

The metric is

$$\begin{pmatrix} R^{2}\operatorname{sech}^2(\psi) & 0 \\ 0 & R^{2}\operatorname{sech}^2(\psi) \\\end{pmatrix}$$

The inverse metric is

$$\begin{pmatrix} R^{-2}\operatorname{cosh}^2(\psi) & 0 \\ 0 & R^{-2}\operatorname{cosh}^2(\psi) \\\end{pmatrix}$$

I've worked the Christoffel symbols out to be

$\Gamma^\theta = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & R^{-4}\cosh^3(\psi)\sinh(\psi) \\ R^{-4}\cosh^3(\psi)\sinh(\psi) & 0 \\\end{pmatrix}$

$\Gamma^\psi = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & R^{-4}\cosh^3(\psi)\sinh(\psi) \\ R^{-4}\cosh^3(\psi)\sinh(\psi) & R^{-4}\cosh^3(\psi)\sinh(\psi) \\\end{pmatrix}$

I wasn't expecting the results to look quite like this, so it makes me wonder if I made any mistakes or miscalculations.

Comment: There is the [Catalogue of Spacetimes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.4184.pdf) but I wouldn't expect this coordinate system to be present.

Comment: If you don't want to use Mathematica, as shown below, it is indeed necessary to do the calculations repeatedly until one is confident of the answer. On the other hand, explicit formulas for Christoffel symbols are rarely used by most differential geometers. There are other ways to represent the Levi-Civita connection that are easier to compute and use.

Comment: This [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/770626/304394) shows how those calculations can be done in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to Mathematica, you can check your results with the following script:

```
dim = 2;
q = {\[Theta], \[Psi]};
p = {R*Cos[\[Theta]]*Sech[\[Psi]], R*Sin[\[Theta]]*Sech[\[Psi]], 
   R*Tanh[\[Psi]]};
g = Simplify[
   Table[D[p, q[[i]]] . D[p, q[[j]]], {i, 1, dim}, {j, 1, dim}]];
inverseg = Simplify[Inverse[g]];
\[CapitalGamma] = 
  Simplify[Table[
    inverseg[[k, k]]*D[p, q[[k]]] . D[D[p, q[[i]]], q[[j]]], {k, 1, 
     dim}, {i, 1, dim}, {j, 1, dim}]];

Riem = Simplify[
   Table[D[\[CapitalGamma][[a, b, d]], q[[c]]] - 
     D[\[CapitalGamma][[a, b, c]], q[[d]]] + 
     Sum[\[CapitalGamma][[i, b, d]]*\[CapitalGamma][[a, i, c]], {i, 1,
        dim}] - 
     Sum[\[CapitalGamma][[i, b, c]]*\[CapitalGamma][[a, i, d]], {i, 1,
        dim}], {a, 1, dim}, {b, 1, dim}, {c, 1, dim}, {d, 1, dim}]];
Ric = Simplify[
   Table[Sum[Riem[[k, i, k, j]], {k, 1, dim}], {i, 1, dim}, {j, 1, 
     dim}]];
\[Kappa] = Sum[inverseg[[i, j]] Ric[[i, j]], {i, 1, dim}, {j, 1, dim}];


\[CapitalGamma]
```

Given also are the formulas for the Riemann tensor (`Riem`) Ricci tensor (`Ric`) and Ricci curvature (`\[Kappa]`).

The output for `\[CapitalGamma]` is

```
{{{0, -Tanh[\[Psi]]}, {-Tanh[\[Psi]], 0}}, {{Tanh[\[Psi]], 
   0}, {0, -Tanh[\[Psi]]}}}
```

Which means

$$\Gamma^1_{1~1}=0 \\ \Gamma^1_{1~2}=\Gamma^1_{2~1}=-\tanh\psi \\ \Gamma^1_{2~2}=0 \\ \Gamma^2_{1~1}=\tanh\psi \\ \Gamma^2_{2~1}=\Gamma^2_{1~2}=0 \\ \Gamma^{2}_{2~2}=-\tanh\psi$$

Or, in your notation
$$\Gamma^\theta=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -\tanh\psi \\ -\tanh\psi & 0\end{pmatrix} \\ \Gamma^\psi=\begin{pmatrix}\tanh\psi & 0 \\ 0 & -\tanh\psi\end{pmatrix}$$

Which is different from your results.

Comment: By the way, the output for the metric `g` is indeed `{{R^2 Sech[\[Psi]]^2, 0}, {0, R^2 Sech[\[Psi]]^2}}`, so there are no mistakes in the script.

Comment: Ok. I want to try again by hand and see where I went wrong. Greatly appreciate you providing that script